How does RWeka calculate probabilities in a KNN model using IBk?
I’m working with the RWeka package in R and have some questions about how probabilities are calculated in a KNN model when using the IBk classifier. I have a classification dataset that is split into training and test sets, where the last column of the dataset is the class label. Here is the code I am using:
frm <- as.formula(paste0(names(tra)[ncol(tra)], " ~ ."))
model <- IBk(formula = frm, data = tra, na.action = na.pass, control = Weka_control(K = 1))
pred <- predict(model, newdata = tst[, -ncol(tst)], type = "prob")

Could someone explain how the probabilities are computed when I use the predict function with type = "prob"? I would like to replicate the results of the package, for example, using K = 1 or K = 5...
Thank you!
